# Fiber bundle $U(n-1)\rightarrow U(n)\rightarrow S^{2n-1}$

Tags: differential-geometry

Can someone help me to visualize geometrically the fiber bundle $U(n-1)\rightarrow U(n) \rightarrow S^{2n-1}$, what are the open sets where it trivializes?

Comment: A fiber bundle trivializes over any contractible open set, so any bundle over $S^k$ trivializes over the complement of a point (and therefore over any proper subset).

Comment: For purposes of intuition, it's probably best 1. To understand homogeneous spaces in general; 2. To think of $S^{2n-1}$ as the unit sphere in $\mathbf{C}^{n}$. It's quite clear that $U(n)$ acts transitively, and the stabilizer of a point is isomorphic to $U(n-1)$.